# How to make CC3200 project with Kaa SDK?

Tags: kaa

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10. Installed Kaa Sandbox and tested with notification demo in terminal. I'm using CCSv7 to program on CC3200. I confused what is correct way to create project in CCS with Kaa SDK generate from Kaa Sandbox. Here is how I do but I can't build project:

1. Generate SDK and run build by cmake with target platform is cc32xx, I use notification example
2. Create new project then include Kaa SDK path
3. Include Kaa file library (*.a): libkaac.a, libextension_user.a, libextension_event.a, libextension_logging.a, libextension_profile.a, libextension_bootstrap.a, libextension_notification.a, libextension_configuration.a, libmbedtls.a, librsa_keygen.a. I'm not sure that need all of them but just include all to prevent error.
4. Copy some code from kaa_demo.c and blinky demo project to my main.c.
5. Hit build. Error occur that libmbedtls.a not build for ARM so I go to folder thirdparty and build it. Solved.
6. Occur another error: Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
   [#10099-D](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Compiler/diagnostic_messages/10099)  program will not fit into available memory.  placement with alignment fails for section ".cinit" size 0xc41 .  Available memory ranges:  cc3200v1p32.cmd /demo1  line 75 C/C++ Problem. I try to increase or decrease stack size but not work.
7. More error: Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
   unresolved symbol __assert_func, first referenced in /opt/ti/kaa-sdk/build/libkaac.a  demo1           C/C++ Problem. This error occur when missing include library file but it occur in another library file so I dont know how to fix.

Anyone can help me or suggest how to make a project for CC3200 with Kaa SDK, in any IDE. Its take me 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of Kaa 0.10.0 release the CC32xx sample applications were broken due to the same issue you mentioned in 7). The binary build did not fit into the CC32xx program memory. That is why whole the CC32xx platform was disabled in the Kaa 0.10.0 Sandbox release.

Now, the issue on the [GitHub](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps) repository is fixed and the CC32xx platform will be re-enabled in the Kaa 0.10.1 Sandbox release (comming soon). So, you can either wait for the Kaa 0.10.1 release or try building the CC32xx application with the CMake from GitHub.

Regarding your question for build from CCSv7 IDE directly you should search for integration of CMake builds into the CCSv7 IDE. Kaa team does not provide such integration for now considering you should use any IDE you prefer for development and build by CMake (manually or from IDE).